# Casting output of BehaviourSubject to a different Type

Tags: angular, typescript, types, rxjs

Lets say we have:

```
private userSource = new BehaviorSubject<UserType1 | UserType2>({});
```

Eventually returns a `UserType3` or maybe dynamic Type, which can be a specific Type but to be agreed upon during the process.

Is it possible to cast the return Type of a BehaviourSubject to different Type?

Comment: It's possible to cast like that: (userSource  as any) as BehaviorSubject<any> , but it's better to declare private userSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>({})

Comment: Does "to be agreed upon during the process" mean at some point during development you might want to change the type options, or does it mean the program might use another type at runtime? If it's the first you can declare a type like `type User = UserType1 | UserType2` so there's only one place to change it in the future. If it's the second you might as well use `any` as the type.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes in mind is using [Discriminated Unions](https://codewithstyle.info/typescript-discriminated-union-types/).

The main idea is that you'll have a **union of types** and all these types will have a common [**singleton type**](https://medium.com/@tar.viturawong/using-typescripts-singleton-types-in-practice-f8b20b1ec3a6).

In short, this is what it will allow you to do:

```js
interface UserTypeOne {
  type?: 't1';
  name: string;
  age:  number;
}

interface UserTypeTwo {
  type?: 't2'
  address: {
    street: string
  }
  city: string;
}

interface UserTypeThree {
  type?: 't3';
  hobbies: string[];
}

/* ... */

type Users = UserTypeOne | UserTypeTwo | UserTypeThree;

/* ... */

const userSource$ = new BehaviorSubject<Users>(null);

/* ... */

switch (u.type) {
      case "t1": {
        console.log('type1', u.age, u.name)

        return;
      }

      case "t2": {
        console.log('type2', u.city, u.address.street)

        return;
      }

      case "t3": {
        console.log('type3', u.hobbies)

        return;
      }      
    }
```

[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vrtyd6?devtoolsheight=60).

Comment: Great! Think this is what I'm looking for, however the demo has an error in it?! `Error in /~/index.ts (18:15) Cannot read property 'type' of null`

Comment: Sorry! It’s because I initialize the BehaviorSubject with null. And then, when subscribing to values, I’m do not apply any filter to the values. Can be solved by using the filter operator to get only truthy values. I’ll fix it ASAP.